# React conditionally show link if there is content on json file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Did some searching around, but could not find anything. this is something simple on jQuery and Rails, but not sure if there is a correct way to to this in React. I have this component that is grabbing its data form a JSON file, and I want to only display a certain link if the JSON has content, otherwise I want to hide it. I tried this way so far with no luck:

```js
 renderList(projectLinks){
  //let self = this;
  return projectLinks.map(function(link) {
   var showDemo = "";
   if(link.urlDemo === ""){
    console.log("i'm empty");
    showDemo = "displayNone";
   }
   return <Panel header={link.title} eventKey={link.eventKey} key={link.title}>
       <p>{link.description}</p>
          <img src={link.image} className="img-thumbnail" alt="project thumbnail"/><br />
         <a href={link.urlDemo} className={showDemo}>Demo </a>
          <a href={link.urlCode}>Code </a>
        </Panel>
  });
 }
```

so, if the json link is empty like this: "urlDemo": "", I want the link to be hidden.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: how about you move the `return` part inside `if` block?

Comment: return `false` or `null` in case of blank url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside render, use conditional operator. Here's an example

```
render(){
   return (
      <div>
          {this.state.check ? <div>Show this if check is true</div> :
              <div>Show this if check is false</div>}
      <div>
   )
}
```

Edit: A more specific example

```
render(){
   return(
      <div>
         {link.urlDemo ? <a href={link.urlDemo}>Demo </a> : null}
      </div>
   )
}
```

Another way of doing the same:

```
render(){
   return(
      <div>
         {link.urlDemo && <a href={link.urlDemo}>Demo </a>}
      </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Thanks @raksheetbhat for your eloquent response.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.